# Convenience of 2D CUDA texture memory against global memory

Tags: cuda, textures

I'm implementing a simple boxcar filter only as an excuse to evaluate the different speed of 2D local texture and global memory accesses.

More in detail, the `.cu` file is the following

```
#include <cuda.h>  
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "cufft.h"
#include "Kernels_Test_Texture_Float.cuh"

#define BLOCK_SIZE_x 16
#define BLOCK_SIZE_y 16

/**********************/
/* TEST TEXTURE FLOAT */
/**********************/
extern "C" void Function_Test_Texture_Float(float* data, float* dev_result, int N1, int N2){

    size_t pitch; 
    float* data_d;
    cudaMallocPitch((void**)&data_d,&pitch, N1 * sizeof(float), N2);
    cudaChannelFormatDesc desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
    cudaBindTexture2D(0,&data_d_texture,data_d,&desc,N1,N2,pitch);
    cudaMemcpy2D(data_d,pitch,data,sizeof(float)*N1,sizeof(float)*N1,N2,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cudaMemset(dev_result,0,sizeof(float)*N1*N2);
    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE_x,BLOCK_SIZE_y); dim3 dimGrid(N1/BLOCK_SIZE_x + (N1%BLOCK_SIZE_x == 0 ? 0:1),N2/BLOCK_SIZE_x + (N2%BLOCK_SIZE_x == 0 ? 0:1));
    Kernel_Test_Texture_Float<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(dev_result,N1, N2);

}

/**************/
/* TEST FLOAT */
/**************/
extern "C" void Function_Test_Float(float* data, float* dev_result2, int N1, int N2){

    float* data_d;  cudaMalloc((void**)&data_d,sizeof(float)*N1*N2);
    cudaMemcpy(data_d,data,sizeof(float)*N1*N2,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 

    cudaMemset(dev_result2,0,sizeof(float)*N1*N2);
    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE_x,BLOCK_SIZE_y); dim3 dimGrid(N1/BLOCK_SIZE_x + (N1%BLOCK_SIZE_x == 0 ? 0:1),N2/BLOCK_SIZE_x + (N2%BLOCK_SIZE_x == 0 ? 0:1));
    Kernel_Test_Float<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(dev_result2,data_d,N1, N2);

}
```

The `.cuh` file is the following

```
texture<float,2> data_d_texture;

/**************************/
/* 2D TEXTURE TEST KERNEL */
/**************************/
__global__ void Kernel_Test_Texture_Float(float* dev_result, int N1, int N2)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int j = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;

    float datum, accumulator=0.;

    int size_x=5;
    int size_y=5;

    if((i<(N1-size_x))&&(j<(N2-size_y)))
    {
        for (int k=0; k<size_x; k++)
        for (int l=0; l<size_y; l++){
            datum = tex2D(data_d_texture,i+k,j+l);
            accumulator = accumulator + datum;
        }
        dev_result[j*blockDim.x*gridDim.x+i] = accumulator;
    }
}

/******************/
/* 2D TEST KERNEL */
/******************/
__global__ void Kernel_Test_Float(float* dev_result2, float* data_d, int N1, int N2)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int j = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;

    float accumulator=0.;

    int size_x=5;
    int size_y=5;

    if((i<(N1-size_x))&&(j<(N2-size_y)))
    {
        for (int k=0; k<size_x; k++)
            for (int l=0; l<size_y; l++){
                accumulator = accumulator + data_d[(j+l)*blockDim.x*gridDim.x+(i+k)];
        }
        dev_result2[j*blockDim.x*gridDim.x+i] = accumulator;
    }
}
```

However, the global memory kernel results much faster than the texture memory kernel (`94us` vs `615us` - the timing is the result of the Visual Profiler - the card is a GeForce GT 540M).

Is there anything wrong in the use I'm doing of the texture memory or global memory is indeed faster than texture being cached?

Thanks in advance for any comment.

Comment: How is the timing being done?

Comment: Which graphic device have you installed?

Comment: @talonmies Information added in the revised post.

Comment: @pQB Information added in the revised post.

Comment: Do you always execute the texture test before the global memory test?

Comment: @Patrik Yes, but I reversed now also the order of the two tests and the timing keeps the same.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you enable compiler optimization? With -O3, the texture version is always faster than the global memory version on my CC 3.0 GPU (GeForce GT 650M). I also tested with a simpler kernel, and the speed are roughly equivalent (texture memory still a bit faster). However, on an older GPU with CC 2.0 (Tesla C2070) and older drivers, I also get a global memory version that is a bit faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general terms the global memory read accesses are faster than the texture memory read. In addition, the GT 540M has a compute capability 2.1, so it has a configurable L1, and L2 cache hierarchy for global memory accesses. Also this cache hierarchy is small, it's bigger than the texture cache.

Considering these two aspects it is not surprising that your global memory implementation is faster than the texture ones.

You probably didn't take into account the L1/L2 cache hierarchy of your device. Depending on the size of the problem, you could find a better performance by maximizing the L1 cache to 48KB before launching your `Kernel_Test_Float` kernel:

```
cudaThreadSetCacheConfig(cudaFuncCachePreferL1);
```

Comment: The comment posted by @Patrik is quite interesting. Despite that comment, the answers should still be correct.

Comment: I can't say I agree with this answer, especially the first sentence. Do you have benchmarks or references to back it up?

Comment: @talonmies I did a test (some months ago in a gtx480) running a morphological gradient on GPU to check neighbors access behaviour, using 2D textures and global memory. The test did not mixed global memory and texture kernels, i.e. runs only global memory first and texture in another execution. The results showed less execution time for the global memory implementation, even with the image boundary check. However, the times were much closer than the ones reported in the question

Comment: @pQB Thanks for your answer. By running `cudaThreadSetCacheConfig(cudaFuncCachePreferL1);` in `Function_Test_Float` before the `Kernel_Test_Float` call the performance keeps the same, also when changing the size of the problem.

Comment: @talonmies I have just found this [paper](http://math.arizona.edu/~dongbin/Publications/GPUImplementations.pdf). If my understanding is correct (see Fig. 4), for a GTX480, which has a compute capability 2.0, global memory storage is preferable as compared to texture memory storage. Should we conclude that, unless implementing (e.g.) linear interpolators (which should be faster when implemented in hardware by texture memory), global memory storage is better than texture memory storage for general purpose applications?

Comment: @pQB: I don't really know about the CC 2.0 explanation, but on a CC 3.0 device, texture memory is faster with the code provided.

Comment: @BenC Good feedback. I didn't know it but in Kepler (CC 3.0) the texture throughput is increased (up to 4x) compared to Fermi. My answer is based on my own experiment. Keeping track of the NVIDIA whitepaper would be a better idea